# On doing ping in Wine and I am getting error message

Tags: wine, ping

I typed this in Wine command prompt:

```
ping www.google.com
```

then I got this message in terminal:

```
fixme:ping:main this command currently just sleeps based on -n parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows that this is a bug in Wine.

Read https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-bugs/2010-September/250327.html

http://osdir.com/ml/wine-bugs/2014-10/msg00689.html

So instead you have just to use the Linux native `ping`